# How can I register components using a convention but dynamically named?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am currently registering multiple objects with specific names, I'd like to do it by convention.

Currently works:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Repository>().Named("Repository1").ImplementedBy<Repository1>());
container.Register(Component.For<Repository>().Named("Repository2").ImplementedBy<Repository2>());

container.Register(
            Component.For<RepositoryFactorySelector, ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().LifestyleSingleton(),
            Component.For<IRepositoryFactory>().AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<RepositoryFactorySelector>()));
```

I've tried:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Repository>().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces());
```

But then my custom Factory and DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector can't find the component by name?

> Requested component named 'Repository2' was not found in the
>   container. Did you forget to register it?

How can I register components using a convention but dynamically named?

Comment: I would use a custom class attribute. If all of your classes will be derived from a single interface or class, you can use such attribute to provide child class name. Maybe [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the windsor page about registering components by convention (http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) the following code snippet should help you:

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
      .BasedOn<ICommon>()
      .LifestyleTransient()
      .Configure(component => component.Named(component.Implementation.FullName + "XYZ"))
```

);

By the way, why don't you change your componentselector to select the correct handler based on implementation type ?

Kind regards,
Marwijn.